# Is it possible to disable access to the "Router Settings" from the Wifi?

Tags: security, wireless-router, mac-address

- For security reasons, I would like to disable the access to the "Router Settings"
  from the Wifi.
- I already set a White-List "Accept" MAC filtering, but there is
  a chance that a potential intruder steals the MAC of one of
  the devices that are on the White List. With that MAC it can
  breaks the Router password.
- If I allow to configure the Router Settings just from a wired connection, it will be more secured.

Is it possible? (To be specific, I have an Asus RT-AC87U Router)

--

EDIT: Of course I have 2 different, long and complex passwords: One for the Wifi, One for the Router Settings.

Comment: It might be possible to cheat a workaround for this. Google tells me the switch you want is not available, but you can set admin access to up to four specific MAC addresses. If you do this for 4 existing Ethernet connections, you've effectively disabled admin over wifi.

Comment: It would be an extreme solution but you might be able to install an alternate firmware, like Tomato, [AsusWRT](https://www.asuswrt-merlin.net/features) or whatever. Or, if the wifi and ethernet are on different IP blocks can you block access to the configuration web pages by dropping traffic from the local wi-fi block to the relevant ports (80, 8080, 443, whatever).

Answer (score 6):

The ASUS article
[How to make my router more secure?](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1039292/)
has the advice that can solve the problem, which is to
setup separate passwords for the wireless network and for the Web GUI.

If the Asus RT-AC87U Router does allow a password for the GUI that is
separate from the wireless password, then an attacker would need to crack
two passwords and not one.

Creating a long and complex password for the GUI will be a sufficient
protection.

Answer (score 0):

*(This is the direction of the solution @Tetsujin suggested in a comment on my question except it seems that it is not possible to "set admin access to up to four specific MAC addresses"; it is possible to set admin access to up to four specific IP addresses")*

It is possible to make a list of admins on an ASUS router. Follow
these steps:

- Open a web browser and enter your ASUS router's IP address into the
  address bar. The default IP address for most ASUS routers is
  `192.168.1.1`.
- Log in to your ASUS router with your username and password. If you
  have never set up a username and password, try using "admin" for
  both.
- Once you're logged in, navigate to the `Administration` tab in the
  router's interface (1).
- Select `System` tab (2) and in the section `Remote Access Config` 
  `Enable Access Restrictions` check `Yes` (3).
- Only then it opens the `Access restriction list (Max Limit: 4)`
  section (4), you'll see a dropdown menu called `Destination IP` and 3 check-boxes called `Access Type`. Here, you can add
  and remove administrators by entering their IP and Access Type restrictions. Click `Add` (4) for each.
- Click "Apply" to save your changes (5).

[image]

- **Yet, I am not sure it gives 100% protection.** *Since an intruder can connect to the Wifi with a static IP and open the Web UI of the router.*